# Set the image background of a panel

Tags: vb.net

I want to change dynamically the background image of my panel named "Panel2" to the image named "2.png" in the application folder.
My code is :

```
img = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "\2.png)
Panel2.BackgroundImage = img
```

But it doesn't work

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What happens when you run the current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be correct.

I think your image is not there, because

```
 Application.StartupPath
```

is a temporaly path in your appdata and not where your project is.

When you just write "\2.png" he should automatically search also in your project folder: \debug.